# Issue in DB2 query execution using JNDI connection in WAS Server

Tags: java, linux, db2, websphere

I am trying to connect DB using JNDI that has configured in WAS Server. How ever I was able to get JNDI connection from my webapplication but unable to trigger any query using JNDI connection. Same queries can be able to trigger from application if I use JDBC connection. Can anybody help me on this. Application is running on Linux..

## Below are the application/os/db server details

Linux version : 2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64
WebSphere Application Server    8.5.5.7 
Database server = DB2/LINUXX8664 10.5.5

Error Details :
for example query : CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD(' export to /downloads/csv/file1.csv OF DEL modified by timestampformat="yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS" SELECT FROM MYVIEWS.EMP_HISTORY WHERE  START_TIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP(''2017-03-15 00:00:00'') AND  TIMESTAMP(''2017-03-21 23:59:59'')  order by EMPNAME ASC ')

Exception : com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: An SQL error "-204" occurred while processing the SELECT string in the Action String parameter.. SQLCODE=-3022, SQLSTATE=     , DRIVER=3.69.24

*Same will be executed success when using JDBC connection..

Kindly help me on this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD` is not a _query_, so it should be executed with an appropriate method.

Comment: According to this IBM KnowledgeCenter topic, https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic1.html, SQL204N implies name is an undefined name.  What log did the exception you pasted above come from? Have you looked for an FFDC or other entries in the WebSphere logs that might display what "name" in the above context is not defined?

Comment: Hi, The log I have pasted from websphere SystemErr.log file.